# Не получается сконвертировать xml в json

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Я делаю конвертер XML ⇆ JSON. При попытке вызвать функцию `xml2json` выскакивает ошибка:

```
Error: Text data outside of root node.
Line: 0
Column: 20
Char: ]
    at error (sax.js:651)
    at strictFail (sax.js:677)
    at SAXParser.write (sax.js:1035)
    at module.exports (xml2js.js:346)
    at Object.module.exports [as xml2json] (xml2json.js:13)
    at xml2json (main.js:44)
    at HTMLButtonElement.convert (main.js:57)
```

Вот код, которые ее вызывает:

```
function xml2json() {
    try {
        let convert = require('xml-js');
        let xmlParser = new DOMParser();
        let xml = xmlParser.parseFromString(rightTextArea.value, 'text/xml');
        console.log(xml);
/*-->*/ leftTextArea.value = convert.xml2json(xml, { compact: false, spaces: 4 });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

`leftTextArea` - форма для JSON-формата
`rightTextArea` - форма для XML-формата
Пример XML, на котором программа некорректно работает

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <id>1</id>
        <firstName>Scarlett</firstName>
        <lastName>Johansson</lastName>
        <photo>http://si.wsj.net/public/resources/images/BN-BY925_mag041_OZ_20140318165119.jpg</photo>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>2</id>
        <firstName>Chris</firstName>
        <lastName>Evans</lastName>
        <photo>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/605082381528096769/gt_sJRot.png</photo>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>3</id>
        <firstName>Jeremy</firstName>
        <lastName>Renner</lastName>
        <photo>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/603945839795412992/XTssKbRC.jpg</photo>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте свой XML к вопросу.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, добавил

Comment: XML правильно сформирован (well-formed). Так что это не проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему, мне в этом помогла вот эта [ссылка](https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js/issues/83). Вот код

```
function xml2json() {
    try {
        let convert = require('xml-js');
        let iconvlite = require('iconv-lite');
        let xml = iconvlite.decode(rightTextArea.value, "UTF-8");
        leftTextArea.value = convert.xml2json(xml, { compact: false, spaces: 4 });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```